# Why does a simple rebase have weird conflicts?

Tags: git, rebase, conflict

Premise: I've never really worked seriously with `rebase`, I've always done some super easy jobs, without really never trying to understand exactly what and why was going on. But now I have to.

I need to delete from the [`imgui-save`](https://github.com/scenerygraphics/scenery/tree/feature/imgui-save) branch [this commit](https://github.com/scenerygraphics/scenery/commit/acd8ac0e25253ad2b97615857ef37211249cc046), which, unfortunately, is not the last one.

Therefore I tried to rebase with `git rebase --onto commitID^ commitID`.
The commit to delete is pretty easy (it's just a jar and a couple of line in the Gradle build script), in the way that it doesn't interact (almost) at all with the successive commits, however, I got conflicts anyway.

For example: what is strange is that the first conflict appears coming from a previous commit in time from a different time-line: [`c943eb91`](https://github.com/scenerygraphics/scenery/commit/c943eb910ededd638cbfabac5840cc95e8e848bc) with files which have nothing to do with it:
[image]

I also tried to use Idea Gui, choosing "rebase from here" on the commit to delete, but I end up with the same conflicts

Also, when I'm trying to resolve them, what does exactly mean the window on the left and the one on the right (I'm using Intellij Idea)? I guess the one on the left is the status at the `c943eb91` commit, but where does the one on the right "Already rebased commits" comes from, time-wise?

[image]

Because I'd assume Git attempting to rebase commit after commit of the same time-line starting from the commit after the dropped one..

Comment: Maybe naive question: why considering rebase instead of just reverting the commit? If changes are specific to a file, it sounds like the easiest way. (But you might have considered and rejected it for some reason specific to your context?)

Comment: Are there merges involved in the rebase?

Comment: @RomainValeri Because I'd like to remove the binary jar completly from the git history

Comment: @eftshift0 In which way? There are merge from time to time from `master` into `imgui-save` to reduce the divergence

Comment: rebase does _not_ consider merges when rebasing by default.... so, you would be missing stuff that is _done_ (on the fly, say.... specially conflict resolutions) in merge commits.. which would explain what you are seeing. Try with `--rebase-merges`.

Comment: ok, so `git rebase --rebase-merges --onto commitID^ commitID`?

Comment: Sounds like it.

Comment: @eftshift0 I think I solved it.. if you want to write it as a solution, I'll accept it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git does *not* rebase merges by default. If there are merges involved in the *to-be-rebased* history where there have been changes added *on the fly* (it can be any change, but think particularly in terms of conflict resolutions) then you will be missing those changes, which could very well explain what you are seeing.

For that, you need the `--rebase-merges` option

Comment: One last question out of curiosity: why isn't this the default option?

Comment: I wouldn't know historically why it was like that _but_ I do know that rebasing merges can be painful because when there are conflicts, git does _not_ consider the previous resolution that was attempted in the original merge.... even if the trees involved are exactly the same (tip commits being merged, common ancestors), git will still ask you to solve the conflicts. I will _someday_ tackle this (I have already asked for feedback on a POC but it was too narrow in scope... will someday sit down to polish a wider POC for this to see if I can ease this a little bit).